# phpMyAdmin Quick database export: is it OK to use it for WordPress database backup?

Tags: backup, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Can somebody confirm/clarify whether using phpMyAdmin Quick database export option is sufficient for backing up WordPress database? Or there is something specific to WordPress database backup that requires going to "Custom - display all possible options" export mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PhpMyAdmin quick export is a perfectly safe way to backup a Wordpress database.

PhpMyAdmin's quick export is configured by default to export the database structure and all the records as SQL.  You can view the contents of this file in notepad to verify that if you wish.

Don't forget to backup your WordPress files, especially in your "uploads" directory as the database will reference them.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, last time I moved WordPress install on different VPS I used standard setting, except I skipped few tables that was generated on receiving host with install script.